# pandas regex matching strings starting from left to right using another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df`, I like to match the `amount` from the left beginning of `inv_id`, and create a boolean column `left_match`, `True` - if there is a match, `False` - othwise,

```
amount    inv_id        
309.9     30990071218
3130.0    313000B20180501
3330.50   3330.5020180425
17.35     13249261 100117
43.2      9037878 020418
```

I will remove any non-numeric chars from `inv_id` first,

```
s = df[inv_id].str.replace(r'\D+', '')
```

then convert `amount * 100` to strings,

```
df['amt_str'] = (df['amount']*100).round().astype(int).astype(str)
```

I am wondering how to use `amt_str` to match `s`. The results should look like,

```
amount    inv_id             left_match        
309.9     30990071218        True
3130.0    313000B20180501    True
3330.50   3330.5020180425    True
17.35     13249261 100117    False
43.2      9037878 020418     False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['left_match'] = df.apply(lambda x:True if re.search(str(x['amount']).split('.')[0],x['inv_id']).start() ==0 else False,axis=1)
df
```

output:

```
amount  inv_id  left_match
0   309.90  30990071218 True
1   3130.00 313000B20180501 True
2   17.35   13249261 100117 False
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
df['inv_id_temp'] = df['inv_id'].str.replace('.','')
df['left_match'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['amt_str']==x['inv_id_temp'][:len(x['amt_str'])],1)

df[['amount', 'inv_id','left_match']]

    amount  inv_id          left_match
0   309.90  30990071218     True
1   3130.00 313000B20180501 True
2   3330.50 33305020180425  True
3   17.35   13249261 100117 False
4   43.20   9037878 020418  False
```

Comment: You can do it without Lambda func, try using Map func.

Comment: @JiteshVacheta Can refer any solution like that to slice series with different values. In fact I searched this but could not find decent solution. Everywhere using apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['inv_id_numeric'] = df['inv_id'].str.replace(r'\D+', '')
df['amt_str'] = (df['amount']*100).round().astype(int).astype(str)
df['left_match'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['inv_id_numeric'].startswith(x['amt_str']), axis=1)
```

output:

```
    amount           inv_id  inv_id_numeric amt_str  left_match
0   309.90      30990071218     30990071218   30990        True
1  3130.00  313000B20180501  31300020180501  313000        True
2  3330.50  3330.5020180425  33305020180425  333050        True
3    17.35  13249261 100117  13249261100117    1735       False
4    43.20   9037878 020418   9037878020418    4320       False
```